# How do I get out of 3D view

Tags: interface, 3d-view, customization

I was working on an intro and then I managed to click a random button and now, all the tabs on the side were replaced by something that looked like this:
[image: The intro for our project after the incident]

I really need to fix this so I can get back on track. So can you guys help me since I'm just new to this Software.

Answer (score 2):

You just switched the editor (window) type.

All you have to do is click on the *Window type button* (first button in the header), and switch the window back to *Properties*.

[image: 3D view header with window type menu open]